# PROC RANK by score: minimum number of a counts of target variable

Tags: sas, rank, proc

I have used SAS PROC RANK to rank a population based on score and create groups of equal size. I would like to create groups such that there is a minimum number of target variable (Goods and Bads) in each bin. Is there a way to do that using PROC RANK? I understand that the size of each bin would be different.

For example in the table below, I have created 10 groups based on a certain score. As you can see the Non cures in the lower deciles are sparse. I would like to create groups such there there are at least 10 Non cures in each group.

Cures and Non cures are based on same variable:  Cure = 1 and Cure = 0.

```
Decile cures   non cures

   0    262      94
   1    314      44
   2    340      19
   3    340      13
   4    353      10
   5    373       5
   6    308       3
   7    342       3
   8    440       4
   9    305       3
```

Comment: I am 99% sure you cannot do this in PROC RANK.  There might be another procedure to do it, but I can't think of one.  You will probably have to roll your own in a DATA Step.

Comment: You could create separate deciles for cures and non-cures - sort your dataset by cure, then add `by cure;` within PROC RANK if you want to do that. If you want one set of quantiles which spans both cures and non-cures then I think DomPazz is right - you'll need decide exactly what logic you want to use, then write a data step for it.